# Unique element for multiple schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have same table (User) in another schemas.
One schema - for one tenant.
User has unique email.
How to set email field like unique for all schemas?

And if this is impossible, can I get all users from another schemas per one hql query?

Comment: I don't think you can have a unique constraint accross schemas (or tables, but I might be wrong on that one) but queries accross schemas in the same database are possible, you just name the tables schema.table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global schema that contains the `users` table. Then for each tenant schema, create a view that selects only the users relevant for that tenant.

```
create schema global;
create schema tenant1;
create schema tenant2;

create table global.users
(
  id serial primary key,
  tenant integer not null,
  email varchar(254) not null unique,
  ... other columns
);

create view tenant1.users
as
select id, email, ... --<<< don't select the tenant here!
from global.users
where tenant = 1
with check option;

create view tenant2.users
as
select id, email, ... --<<< don't select the tenant here!
from global.users
where tenant = 2
with check option;
```

The views are automatically updateable without any triggers.

The base table **and** the views must be owned by a different database user then the other tables in each tenant's schema. That "global" user then has to grant the select, insert, update, delete privileges (only) on the views, to prevent the database user used for each tenant to be able to see the other tenant's data.

Comment: I still have a question.
My user entity have one to many join to user_permission.
So one user can have many permission: admin, user, etc.
How can i write a view, and map it to take something like this:

user {
id
email
list<permission>
}

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard feature to ensure uniqueness across many schemas. You can implement this using common table like in the following example.

Existing tables.

```
create schema tenant1;
create schema tenant2;
create table tenant1.users (email text);
create table tenant2.users (email text);
```

Create a common table and a function for triggers:

```
create schema sys;

create table sys.emails (email text primary key);

create or replace function sys.email_trigger()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if tg_op = 'INSERT' then
        insert into sys.emails 
        values (new.email);
    elsif tg_op = 'UPDATE' then
        update sys.emails 
        set email = new.email 
        where email = old.email;
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;
```

Define triggers for all `users` tables:

```
create trigger users_before_insert_or_update
before insert or update on tenant1.users
for each row execute procedure sys.email_trigger();

create trigger users_before_insert_or_update
before insert or update on tenant2.users
for each row execute procedure sys.email_trigger();
```

And try to insert the same email in two tables:

```
insert into tenant1.users values ('abc@some.com');
insert into tenant2.users values ('abc@some.com');

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "emails_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(abc@some.com) already exists.
```

You can access tables in different schemas in one query using *full names* of the tables, e.g. use union to list all users:

```
select * from tenant1.users
union all
select * from tenant2.users;
```

Comment: I tried with union all, but i need something more dynamical. Because when i run app i don't know how many schemas i have, so i need to add extra logic to get all schemas name and build query on fly, so i don`t like this way. But thanks.